# ansible/aws: test ssh connectivity to private ec2 instances via ssh config file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible

I have set up a list of `ec2` instances to which I can log into using a `ssh.cfg` file that performs proxying & agent forwarding via the publicly accessible NAT instance as follows:

```
ssh -F ssh.cfg admin@private_instance_ip
```

`ssh.cfg` has the following structure:

```
Host 10.40.*
  ProxyCommand           ssh -W %h:%p ec2-user@nat_instance_ip -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no


Host *
  ControlMaster          auto
  ControlPath            ~/.ssh/mux-%r@%h:%p
  ControlPersist         60m
  ForwardAgent           yes
```

My network is of course `10.40.*`.

I want to test ansible connectivity to such hosts (defined in `inventoryfile`) as follows:

```
ansible -i inventoryfile -m ping all
```

Is there a way to do this?

**edit**: an example of how the `ansible ping` fails:

```
ansible -i inventoryfile -m ping 10.40.187.22

10.40.187.22 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

**However**:

```
ssh -F ssh.cfg admin@10.40.187.22
Last login: Fri Oct 27 07:36:05 2017 from private_ip_of_NAT
admin@ip-10.40.187.22:~$ exit
```

Here is the `ansible.cfg`

```
[defaults]
nocows = 1
callback_whitelist = profile_tasks
host_key_checking = False
retry_files_enabled = False
gathering = explicit
forks=50
vault_password_file = .vault

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -F ssh.cfg
pipelining = True
```

**edit2**: when specifying user in the `ping` command, it still gives me an error:

```
ansible -i inventoryfile -m ping 10.40.187.22 -u admin

10.40.187.22 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that private `IP`s won't work in `ansible ping` when the later is proxied via e.g. a public nat instance.

The inventory file is dynamic and based on `aws` tags, i.e.

```
[ec2_hosts:children]
tag_Name_my_srv1
tag_Name_my_srv2
```

so the following command succeeds:

```
ansible -i inventoryfile -m ping tag_Name_my_srv1 -u admin

10.40.187.22 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
```